# ERROR: Could not install packages due to an EnvironmentError: [Errno 28] No space left on device - while trying to run streamlit in docker

Tags: docker, docker-compose, streamlit

I am trying to run streamlit in docker. I am referring to the code from the github repository located at: https://github.com/domoritz/streamlit-docker

I am getting the following error when I execute the `docker-compose up` command:

```
ERROR: Could not install packages due to an EnvironmentError: [Errno 28] No space left on device 
ERROR: Service 'streamlit' failed to build: The command '/bin/sh -c pip install -r requirements.txt' returned a non-zero code: 1
```

Can someone help me resolve this issue?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The portion of your hard drive dedicated to Docker images, containers, and other data is full. You have two options:

1. Increase the size of the docker disk image.

On a Mac, open Docker preferences and go to the "Resources" tab. The option "Disk image size" is what you will need to increase to create more space.

2. Clean up unused or old data.

[The docker docs explain some steps for deleting "unnecessary containers and images" here](https://docs.docker.com/docker-for-mac/space/#delete-unnecessary-containers-and-images). The guide is thorough and well-written. The short version is that you can typically run `docker system prune` to free up a good amount of space by removing "all stopped containers, unused networks, dangling images, and build cache"